# Continuous $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ with dense image is surjective?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be continuous with dense image. Must $f$ be surjective?

Intuitively it seems true, I can't picture a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ satisfying this without covering everything. In the case $n=1$, I can prove it quite easily using intermediate value theorem.

Comment: You may be thinking of the related fact that if $f : [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]^n$ has dense image, then it *is* surjective. This is because $[0,1]$ is compact, so its image is compact, and therefore closed (as $[0,1]^n$ is Hausdorff), and a "dense closed set" must be the entire space.

Comment: For subsequent questions, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 7):

No, $f$ need not be surjective. It is not too hard to imagine a space-filling-like curve that misses isolated points.

Indeed, take any plane-filling curve and map it to a new curve in the plane by way of the complex exponential map $z\mapsto e^z$. This is space-filling except it never hits the origin.

Even more, if you take a space-filling curve and map its $y$-component through the $\arctan$ function you get a curve that fills the strip $\Bbb R\times(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. If you then map this through $z\mapsto e^{2z}$, you get a continuous map with dense image that misses the entire negative real number line.

Comment: Can you easily make it miss all the lattice points?

Comment: @user21820 Miss exactly the lattice points? I don't know. Probably, but I can't think of a way right now. Miss the lattice points and a whole lot more? I believe it can be done. Do $\arctan$ like in my second example to make a strip, and scale it to be $1$ unit wide. Now make that strip snake around in the plane (like the video game Snake, if that's an image that helps) so it does cover every (open) grid cell. You can do it mostly piecewise linearly (again like in the game) if you're a little careful how you turn to make sure you fill all the corners of the square you turn in.

Comment: I do mean to miss exactly the lattice points. =D $\quad\quad$ Then again, doesn't your idea succeed? You just make your strip snake around and make sure to cover increasingly further lattice squares minus the lattice points, by going around each lattice point at least once each. No?

Comment: @user21820 Of course, that would work! Focusing on turning around the grid points would even make it easier to imagine she understand, compared to focusing on traversing and filling the cells.

Answer (score 5):

No, a continuous function with dense image is not necessarily surjective. Let us consider a sequence of points $(x_n)_{n\in {\bf N}}$ that is dense in ${\bf R}^n$. Consider the function that sends the interval $[n,n+1]$ to the segment $[x_n, x_{n+1}]$. This gives a function from $[0, \infty)$ to ${\bf R}^n$ whose image contains the dense set of points ${x_n}$ and is contained in a countable union of straight lines.

A countable union of straight lines has a dense complement by the [Baire category theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem). Note also that a countable union of straight lines is of zero two dimensional Lebesgue measure. It has zero area.